# HERE Maps JS API v3: listen to `clusteringend` event

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

Is there any convenient way to tell whether the clustering process has finished/ended? I don't seem to see any native `clusteringend` event in [the clustering provider](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-clustering-provider.html) that I can listen to.

Have been bangin' my head again since the last couple of days on this issue. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, whatever. Rather than waiting for some disappointing answer from some HERE Maps rookie, I tried to work around my issue and made something freaky like so (haven't tested it thoroughly but it's been working quite well so far):

```
var
/*
 * Work "listen-to-clusteringend-event-issue" around.
 */
processedNoisePointCounter   = 0,
incrementProcessedNoisePoint = function () {
    processedNoisePointCounter++;

    if (processedNoisePointCounter === dataPoints.length) {
        map.dispatchEvent('clusteringend');
    }
},
clusteredDataProvider        = new H.clustering.Provider([]),
defaultTheme                 = clusteredDataProvider.getTheme(),
customTheme                  = {

    /**
     *
     * @implements {H.clustering.ITheme.getClusterPresentation}
     */
    getClusterPresentation: function (cluster) {
        var clusterMarker = defaultTheme.getClusterPresentation.call(defaultTheme, cluster);

        cluster.forEachEntry(function (entry) {

            if (!entry.isCluster()) {
                incrementProcessedNoisePoint();
            }
        });

        return clusterMarker;
    },

    /**
     *
     * @implements {H.clustering.ITheme.getNoisePresentation}
     */
    getNoisePresentation: function (noisePoint) {
        var noiseMarker = defaultTheme.getNoisePresentation.call(defaultTheme, noisePoint);

        incrementProcessedNoisePoint();

        return noiseMarker;
    }
};

clusteredDataProvider.setTheme(customTheme);
clusteredDataProvider.setDataPoints(dataPoints);

var layer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
map.addLayer(layer);

map.addEventListener('clusteringend', function () {
    var message = 'Clustering allegedly ends. ;)';

    console.log(message);
    window.alert(message);
});
```

The JSFiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/yvv9wny2/).